Collection page custom filter using metafield not working


I'm having trouble getting metafields to work with my products on Shopify. I'm on the Basic plan, and I've tried setting up metafields, but they don't seem to be functioning correctly. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue or provide guidance on how to properly use metafields with products on a Shopify Basic plan?



query tumbleDryProducts {
  collection(handle: "states") {
    handle
    products(
      first: 10
      filters: {productMetafield: {namespace: "custom", key: "state",      value: "Kerala"}}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          metafield(namespace: "custom", key: "state"){
            key
            namespace
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



